# Update sql table with foreach

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a record set that I need to update with each row.

```
Contract Number  Reference Number

1488126698627   112082
0000926775991   629013
0000926775991   
1808199032200   928022
0000526840337   630422
0000526840337   
0000527102517   
0000527102517   117312
0000527135329   941407
0082100091988   112310
0082100091988   
1808199524881   21435
0000927142120   80960
2223200018220   334370
2972200000048   335784  
0000927055614   
0000927055614   328196
```

What kind of statement can I run where the logic equates to:

For each row of my record set, if the reference number is null and it has a matching contract number, set the reference number equal to the reference number of the matching contract.

So the contract number 0000526840337 has 4 rows, but only 1 row has a reference number, I need to copy the reference number of 630422 into the other 3 matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
update recordset t join
       (select ContractNumber, max(ReferenceNumber) as ReferenceNumber
        from recordset t
        group by ContractNumber
       ) tt
       on t.ContractNumber = tt.ContractNumber
    set t.ReferenceNumber = tt.ReferenceNumber
    where t.ReferenceNumber is null;
```

Comment: This is really close, but recordset is a temptable, and I can not use an alias for my temp table in the UPDATE

Comment: @CalvinSmith . . . I am not aware of a restriction on the use of aliases for a temp table in an `update`.  Can you update your question with your attempted query?

Comment: sorry Gordon. I had to play with it before I got it to work. Thank you.